# How to enable instamojo sandbox (test mode) Mode

Tags: php, codeigniter, instamojo

I have integrated **instamojo** payment gateway in **Codeigniter**. I want to enable sandbox mode in instamojo payment gateway, i can not see any option to change mode to sandbox or test mode.Can anyone tell me how to change that.
Thank You in Advance.

Comment: You should check what is sandbox `$endpoint` and set your code to that. Find it on payment gateway provider docs.

Comment: Are you using Instamojo's [PHP wrapper](https://github.com/Instamojo/instamojo-php) there?

Comment: I have alrady tried to find in provided doc but i am not getting @Tpojka.

Comment: Yes I am using [PHP Wrapper](https://github.com/Instamojo/instamojo-php)  @AshwiniChaudhary

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `Instamojo` class initializer accepts a third argument that can be used to specify the API URL, it defaults to: https://www.instamojo.com/api/1.1/

Hence for the test environment you can do:

```
$api = new Instamojo\Instamojo(
           '[API_KEY]',
           '[AUTH_TOKEN]',
           'https://test.instamojo.com/api/1.1/');
```

---

Note that for this to work you'll have to create an account on https://test.instamojo.com first and also make sure you're using the credentials from https://test.instamojo.com/developers/.

Comment: Ok Thank you very much @AshwiniChaudhary

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary can we add instamojo in CodeIgniter. if you have any suggestion link then please suggest in a comment. thanks

Comment: @ankitsuthar There's no plugin for CodeIgniter from our end. You will have to use our API and roll out something of your own: https://docs.instamojo.com/v1.1/docs

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary sir, can you please tell me what to do when i have to change the test server to go live server. I mean i have done testing so i want to move it to live ? what should i do?

Comment: @ankitsuthar Start using your production API key, Auth token and simply remove the third argument(as it by default points to production).

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary Thanks for the reply sir , so you are telling me that so now on i can remove  `api_url`  and just need the `api_key` & `auth_token` ?

Comment: @ankitsuthar Exactly.